# How to inspect/check hover state of any element using inspect element

Tags: html, css, browser, hover, web-inspector

How to inspect an element that only appears while I'm hovering another element? As soon as I hover out, the element disappears.

I'm not too sure if the hover effect is done with a CSS class or javascript though.

Comment: Inspect the element that you are hovering. Then watch the DOM changes as you hover it with the mouse. Usually you either see a CSS class toggle on the Element that is about to appear. Then you can apply that class manually. Or select the elemen that should be visible manually (if its visible in the DOM) and apply inline CSS to make it visible

Comment: Hmm so the hover effect is not done with a CSS class then as it doesn't toggle on hover.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its depend on which browser you are using. there is option to select the hover state.

Chrome as a Example:

[image: Chrome Inspect]

Comment: Damn, It seems that the hover effect is not done with a CSS class as a class doesn't toggle when I hover or unhover.

Comment: Its not a class its state, each element has this state so when ever you tick that checkbox and if there any action then that will reflect in browser.